# Is there a name for (the shape of) linking two hands by gripping wrists?

Tags: terminology, gestures

Is there a term for this form of holding hands in which each person grips the other's wrist, as might be used to form a strong link in a kid's game like Red Rover or in an action movie after catching a falling person by the arm?

How would you describe the 3D shape made by the the forearms and hands in this position?

Comment: Are you really asking about the shape itself or a name for that grip?

Comment: My original goal was to describe a geometric figure that has roughly this shape (the interior of [Bing's house](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/House_with_two_rooms)), so either would do.

Comment: I'd describe it as "gripping each other by the wrist" although I see "gripping each other by the forearm" used as well. Not very concise, but clear and descriptive.

Comment: How about *forearm grip*?

Answer (score 1):

After another round of trying search terms, I found "[forearm handshake](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/10186/does-the-forearm-grip-handshake-have-a-historical-basis)". I was hoping to find something well-known enough to have its own Wikipedia article, but this should work.

Comment: I think just 'forearm shake' would make more sense, but the 'hand' in 'handshake' might be more symbolic than literal.